# Ada tag comparison causes compiler to crash

Tags: gcc, segmentation-fault, ada, gnat

I'm not sure if this is a bug in my version of gcc (4.8.5) or gprbuild (2.2.0) but when I try to compile a project there is a specific function whose body causes the compiler to crash with a `STORAGE_ERROR`. When I build with `-cargs -v` I see that `gnatl -quiet ...` is the command that is most recently output before the crash.

The function in question produces an informative string from a tag belonging to a particular type hierarchy. It looks something like:

```
function Tag_To_String (From : Ada.Tags.Tag) return String is (
    if From = A'Tag then "This is tag A"
    elsif From = B'Tag then "This is tag B"
    --  ...
    elsif From = Z'Tag then "This is tag Z"
    else "");
```

Whereas I can get it to successfully compile if I change that body to:

```
function Tag_To_String (From : Ada.Tags.Tag) return String is ("");
```

The error I get is exactly:

```
gcc -c -gnat12 sourcefile.adb

raised STORAGE_ERROR : stack overflow or erroneous memory access
gprbuild: *** compilation phase failed
```

Any idea why gcc can't seem to compile this particular function?

Comment: GCC 4.8.5 may simply be too close to the introduction of expression functions.  I.e. a bug in an early implementation of the compilation of expression functions.  As Jim Rogers writes, it works fine with a more recent version of the compiler.

Comment: This seems most likely. I'll update my tooling. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following program works properly using the 2018 release of GNAT and GPS.

```
with Ada.text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Tags; use Ada.Tags;

procedure Tag_Main is
   package foo is
      type A is tagged private;
      type B is tagged private;
   private
      type A is tagged null record;
      type B is tagged null record;
   end foo;

   use Foo;

   function Tag_To_String(From : Ada.Tags.Tag) return String is(
      if From = A'Tag then
         "This is tag A"
      else
         "This is tag B"
      );

begin
   Put_Line(Tag_To_String(A'Tag));
   Put_Line(Tag_To_String(B'Tag));
end Tag_Main;
```

Note that I have edited the code to use a function expression. It still works on the GNAT/GPS 2018 release.
This version was compiled with gprbuild -d -PD

Comment: That is because my function uses an expression function http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/2xrm/html/RM-6-8.html it should still be valid.

Comment: I've confirmed that the old version of gcc seems to have trouble with the expression function. Changing it to a normal function or updating to a newer gcc both fixed the issue.